# Flickering Image in Java?

Tags: java, image, game-engine

OK so I am coding a game right now to prepair for Ludum Dare SharkJam, and I am using a new method for programming, because the last method I had crashes my PC, so this one should work. Well it does work and all, better too, but the images that I put in it flicker. Here is the whole main class (where the images are drawn)
    package me.NoahCagle.watermaze;

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import me.NoahCagle.watermaze.entity.EntityShark;
import me.NoahCagle.watermaze.entity.Player;
import me.NoahCagle.watermaze.input.Keys;
import me.NoahCagle.watermaze.map.Map;

public class Game extends JFrame {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

Map map = new Map(0, 0);
Player player = new Player(50, 30);
static EntityShark shark = new EntityShark(400, 400);
public Image dbImage;

public Game() {
    setSize(800, 600);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
    setTitle("Water Maze");
    setResizable(false);
    setBackground(Color.blue);
    addKeyListener(new Keys());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Game();
    Thread s = new Thread(shark);
    s.start();
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    dbImage = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    g.drawImage(dbImage, map.x, map.y, null);
    g.drawImage(player.player, player.x, player.y, this);
    g.drawImage(shark.shark, shark.x, shark.y, this);
    repaint();
}


}
```

What this code does for me is makes the Images work correctly, just flickering, alot. Can anyone help me with my issue?
EDIT:
I think it has something to do with where I call the repaint method in the paint method, so look there.

Answer (score 3):

## Problems and suggestions:

- One problem is that you're drawing directly in the `paint` method of a JFrame, and this will cause flickering because you don't get automatic double buffering. Instead draw in the `paintComponent` method of a JPanel to take advantage of the automatic double buffering that comes with swing JComponents.
- Next, you're calling `repaint()` from within `paint` which is a terrible and uncontrollable way to do animation. Use a Swing Timer instead for your animation loop.
- Next, you're creating an image object within the `paint` method. Anything that slows down the paint method or the paintComponent method will slow the responsiveness of your drawing and animation. Don't do this. Avoid creating objects within these methods, but instead use the paintComponent method for drawing and drawing only.
- Next, you don't call the super method. Call `super.paintComponent(g)` within your `paintComponent` override.
- Also, whenever overriding a method, be sure to preface it with the `@Override` annotation so the compiler will notify you if your method signature is wrong.

Comment: @NoahCagle: no, I believe that `paintComponent` is protected, not public, so you'd use that visibility modifier, you'd call the super method, and you'd again not call repaint.

Answer (score 1):

Don't call repaint() from your paint() methods. Use double-buffering (you can switch this on for Swing components) and flicker should be gone.

For animation, you'll need to calculate & update positions each frame. To make this smooth, measure the time delta using `System.nanoTime()`. This will give you much more accurate & smooth animation that `System.currentTimeMillis()`, `new Date()`, or other standard clock-sources.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but 25fps is 40 milliseconds...just how many frames a second are aiming for :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer try it! On Windows at least there'll be a much less slick & smooth quality of animation if you rely on  `System.currentTimeMillis()` as a timing source. FPS: you should aim for 50-100, high is generally better, but not depend on achieving full frame-rate as graphics- and processor--intensive scenes may reduce it. This is the reason for _measuring_ time, not just _assuming_ it..

Comment: I don't disagree with measuring time, I'm curious as to the need to use nanosecond precision, especially given the fact the Swing uses a passive rendering engine. I'm also curious about the need to have such a high frame rate to start with...

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I gave him 1+ just because I think it such a good idea to measure delta time and adjust animation based on this.

Comment: `System.currentTimeMillis()`, on Windows, returns from a clock with 18.21 millisecond ticks. Relying on that means you never measure any intervals between those ticks..  Animation works, but it's definitely not smooth or slick. Change to `System.nanoTime` and you've got smooth measurement well below millisecond accuracy. Each frame is perfectly rendered for the millisecond it pumps out. Voila!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm not disputing the idea of measuring time and adjusting the delay between frames dynamically, I'm just curious as to the need to use nanosecond precision and given the fact that Swing uses a passive rendering engine and delegates it repaints to the event queue, it's actually impossible to know when or how long a frame took to paint, only the time it took to prepare the state

Comment: @ThomasW Thank you, that's very interesting, I appreciate you taking the time